# v1.5.1 of FullCalendar Scheduler is incompatible with v3.0.1 of the core

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

i'm developping an application to schedule events. I'm using fullcalendar.js to get the calendar and i want to use vertical resource view of scheduler.js.
 so i have added scheduler.js but it didn't work.
 On my console i have this message :

```
> v1.5.1 of FullCalendar Scheduler is incompatible with v3.0.1 of the
> core.
```

i'm using fullcalendar 3.2.0 and scheduler 1.5.1

> what have i to do to make vertical resource view working.

Comment: Are you sure you are definitely using fullcalendar 3.2.0 because the v3.0.1 is referring to that version

Comment: yes. cache problem. thank you